# Javascript regex match custom tags outer/inner problem

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex

I found this difficult to explain (and search for) so let me try with an example.

The goal is a template system for a nodejs backend where I can replace custom tags in an HTML template with specific content based on certain params such as language.

A simple replace example:

```
<h1>{static||header}</h1>
```

My custom tag here can be replaced with:

```
template = template.replace(/{static\|\|(.*?)}/g, (match, $1) => { /* find the variable to replace $1 ("header") with and return */});
```

A more complex example where I loop through an array:

```
<ul>{static||items||loop||<li id="%k">%v</li>}</ul>
```

the code to replace it:

```
template = template.replace(/{static\|\|(.*?)}/g, (match, $1) => {
  // static parts
  let parts = $1.split("||");
  if(parts[1] === "loop"){
   /* loop through the "items" array replacing %k and %v as appropriate in parts[2] */
  }
});
```

But now I have run into a new challenge I need to solve and my regex ability is somewhat lacking to solve this so I am turning to StackOverflow for ideas.

The problem I need to solve is a loop, as above, but within that loop are more tags, these could be simple replacements or looped replacements. The point is, the regex needs to find the closing } for the outer tag and ignore any tags and variables that are within it.

Html example:

`<ul>{static||items||loop||<li id="%k">
  <strong>{static||foo}: %v</strong>
  <ul>{static||subitems||loop||<li>%v</li>}</ul>
 </li>}</ul>`

So the regex should match the first "{static" to the last "}" and ignore the 2 "{static...}" that are within it. How can the regex "know" that the correct closing "}" is the last one?

Many thanks!

Comment: S.O. generally doesn't like people using regex on HTML. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252390/the-famous-tag-regex-answer-should-its-title-be-edited

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses

Comment: the html here is irrelevant. the template could be any kind of content.

Comment: the 546433 post is interesting @Adelin, recursion/nesting seems to be a challenge in javascript regex, but will see what I can do with the example provided there.

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly good use case for regex. When your examples keep adding complexity to the point where you're needing recursion and bracket matching, it's probably time to switch to a parser. It's not so much your regex ability as it is the tool itself, which simply is poorly equipped to handle counting and nesting.